# How to post/trigger events to invisible controls in PowerBuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a scenario where some windows are required to be automated non-visually from a controller window, that opens, sets parameters and send events to the other windows controls, like SetFocus (mostly text boxes) and Clicked (exclusively to buttons).

The process works fine when the controlled windows are visible, but it doesn't work when they are invisible.

It's a MDI application.

I tried to set the Width and Height of controlled windows to 0, but the title bar still shows up. The controller window can't be application modal (Response kind).

Some ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always open the 'invisible' window outside of the visible portion of the screen (say at x position of -200 or similar).  Set the windows X position to some negative number in the Open event (the open event is triggered prior to the window being displayed).

Comment: Sounds nice! I'll try it out and give you a feedback after the test.

Comment: Worked fine with this solution!